# three LI column in a single UL CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to recreate the Windows 8 application menu ( the new "start menu" )

My goal is to have square divs with a descriptive text next to it, the column splits itself up when it reaches a certain point ( something I have yet to determine but Iv'e come quite far with this )

In other words: I am trying to make a column that goes down and splits itself into 3 columns automatically and beginnen at the left side again after it has reached the end of the wrapper width.

as you can see in my JFIDDLE Iv'e made something that comes quite close.

http://jsfiddle.net/Qq98X/

Stil I can't seem to find the correct solution for this.
Mainly because i cannot use NTH-CHILD etc properties because it is meant to work on IE7

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .mp-submenu {
            margin-bottom: 1px;
            position:relative;
        }

            .mp-submenu ul{
                max-width:500px;
                max-height:300px;
                list-style:none;
            }

            .mp-submenu ul li{
                float:left;
            }

            #triple li  { width:30.333%; }

        .mp-submenu-square-dg, 
        .mp-submenu-square {
            float:left;
            margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
            padding:5px;
            width:50px;
            height:50px;
            background-color: #8D8D8D;
        }

        .mp-submenu-square-dg:hover, 
        .mp-submenu-square:hover {
            background-color: #F17B0A;
        }

        .mp-submenu-square-dg {
            background-color: #696969;
        }

        .mp-submenu-headletter {
            margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
            font: normal 27px arial;
            text-align: left;
            vertical-align:bottom;
            width:50px;
            height:50px;
            color: black;
            display:inline-block;
            background-color:none;
            float:left;
        }

        .mp-submenu-headletter-desc {
            padding-top:35px;
            font: normal 12px arial;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <article class="mp-submenu">
        <ul id="triple">
            <li>
                <div class="mp-submenu-headletter">A</div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="mp-submenu-square">1</div>
                <div class="mp-submenu-headletter-desc">Beschrijving</div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="mp-submenu-square-dg">2</div>
                <div class="mp-submenu-headletter-desc">Beschrijving</div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="mp-submenu-square">3</div>
                <div class="mp-submenu-headletter-desc">Beschrijving</div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="mp-submenu-square-dg">4</div>
                <div class="mp-submenu-headletter-desc">Beschrijving</div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="mp-submenu-square">5</div>
                <div class="mp-submenu-headletter-desc">Beschrijving</div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="mp-submenu-headletter">B</div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="mp-submenu-square">1</div>
                <div class="mp-submenu-headletter-desc">Beschrijving</div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="mp-submenu-square-dg">2</div>
                <div class="mp-submenu-headletter-desc">Beschrijving</div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="mp-submenu-square">3</div>
                <div class="mp-submenu-headletter-desc">Beschrijving</div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="mp-submenu-square">1</div>
                <div class="mp-submenu-headletter-desc">Beschrijving</div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="mp-submenu-headletter">C</div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="mp-submenu-square">1</div>
                <div class="mp-submenu-headletter-desc">Beschrijving</div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="mp-submenu-square-dg">2</div>
                <div class="mp-submenu-headletter-desc">Beschrijving</div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="mp-submenu-square-dg">3</div>
                <div class="mp-submenu-headletter-desc">Beschrijving</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </article>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```css
#triple li:nth-child(3n+1) {clear:both}
```

This will cause every third item beginning from the first to clear the float and start a new row.

Comment: I'm very grateful for your reply, I forget to mention that I cannot use nth-child properties because the thing has to work for IE7 ( that would have saved my ass indeed )

thanks for the quick reply either way!

Comment: Damn. Well, in that case, you will need to set an explicit height on your `li` elements, so that all of the items are the same height and don't mess up on clearing "naturally".

Comment: Can't you give every third item an extra class, with style `clear:both`?

Comment: @both 

Thanks for the replies, I will try both possible solutions.Thank god for this site btw.

Comment: The squares now stack a little closer together, but setting a height on the wrapper or UL is totaly ignored.

http://jsfiddle.net/Qq98X/1/

Comment: Ah, add `vertical-align:top` as well.

Comment: Yes. In the same place as you added the fixed height.

Comment: ah thank you, it looks real tidy now!

The only think that's left is the fact that the LI items now stack horizontally, do you think there's a way they might stack above eachother? Like so:

http://i58.tinypic.com/33mvjfl.jpg

( please ignore the dutch text )

Comment: Yes, sorry, I tend to make things too difficult for myself.

I am REALLY close to the end-result now, but the thing is is that the "reading direction" is going to the right, like, the squares are now next to eachother in code ( it looks like they are on top of eachother in the browser )

But they actually need to be on top of eachother, with the reading direction of the entire thing going downards.

Are you following me?

Comment: Right now, you have a layout like `123/456` (two lines of three in this example). Are you saying you're trying to get `135/246` instead?